# How is the string representation of a MongoDB ObjectID generated? (In the shell)

Tags: string, mongodb

In the MongoDB shell, if I type `someDoc._id`, Mongo replies with something like `ObjectId(4f6b83af44c75956279e7777)`.  How is that string generated from the [ObjectId bytes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification)?

Links to the javascript source for this are welcome, as are links to the source for other drivers.

Comment: It's the reference object addr? It's habitually a blackbox function which generate the hash, why do you need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that comes from [`BSONElement::toString`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.0/bson/bson-inl.h#L751):

```
case jstOID:
    s << "ObjectId('";
    s << __oid() << "')";
    break;
```

And [`__oid()`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.0/bson/bsonelement.h#L207) gives you a `mongo::OID` and the [`<<` operator](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.0/bson/oid.h#L111) calls `str`:

```
inline StringBuilder& operator<< (StringBuilder& s, const OID& o) { return (s << o.str()); }
```

and that just calls [`toHexLower`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.0/bson/oid.h#L58) on the raw bytes:

```
string str() const { return toHexLower(data, 12); }
```

Finally, [`toHexLower`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.0/util/hex.h#L52) does this:

```
inline string toHexLower(const void* inRaw, int len) {
    static const char hexchars[] = "0123456789abcdef";

    StringBuilder out;
    const char* in = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(inRaw);
    for (int i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        char c = in[i];
        char hi = hexchars[(c & 0xF0) >> 4];
        char lo = hexchars[(c & 0x0F)];

        out << hi << lo;
    }

    return out.str();
}
```

The stringification isn't done in JavaScript, it is done in C++.

The above uses the 2.0 branch of MongoDB but the (current) master is the same (or nearly so).

Comment: thanks for walking through the code in your reply.  very helpful!

Comment: oh, one quick clarification request, since operators are notoriously hard to google and i'm not a C++ person -- can you explain (or link to an explanation of) the `<<` and `>>` operators?  i figure it's a bitshift thing but not certain.  and, i assume `&` is an AND bitmask?

Comment: @ericsoco: The `<<` operator is often used to append or write something to a buffer in C++ so `out << hi << lo` appends `hi` and then `lo` to `out`. There's always [symbolhound.com](http://symbolhound.com/) if you need to search.

Comment: +1, above and beyond for finding the actual code. Thanks for pointing out symbolhound.com, also.

Comment: @WesFreeman: I had to verify my guess so I made and shared my notes :) I came across symbolhound here, share and share alike.